# 'cd ..' is not working in system("") in c++ code running in ubantu environment

Tags: c++, linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

Currently I am in test directory and I am trying to change directory from test to src and run another .so file
below is the code

```
system("cd ..");
system("cd src");
system("./shapessenderros2");
```

folder structure is
test and src folders are in same directory

Comment: Each call to `system()` starts a new independent shell. You will have to combine all commands in a single `system()` perhaps execute a shell script

Comment: Step 1: start a shell, change working directory to the parent, close shell.  Step 2: start a shell, change working directory to the subdirectory src, close shell.  Step 3: start a shell, execute a program in the current working directory, close shell.  You can instead change the current working directory with [std::filesystem::current_path](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/current_path).

Comment: `system("cd ..\ncd src\n./shapessenderros2")` try this (I've used `\n` (newline) to separate commands).

Comment: You could use && to separate commands and other ways here: [https://dev.to/0xbf/run-multiple-commands-in-one-line-with-and-linux-tips-5hgm](https://dev.to/0xbf/run-multiple-commands-in-one-line-with-and-linux-tips-5hgm)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each `system` call creates a new sub shell and whatever you do to the envionment of such a shell will not affect any other sibling shells. Each process inherits the environment from the parent process. You could get around the problem by running all the commands in the same shell:

```
system("cd ../src;./shapessenderros2");
```

or, only execute the command if `cd` succeeds:

```
system("cd ../src && ./shapessenderros2");
```

Or set the correct directory before calling `system`:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <filesystem>

// ...

auto owd = std::filesystem::current_path(); // save the current directory
std::filesystem::current_path("../src");    // change directory
std::system("./shapessenderros2");          // run the command
std::filesystem::current_path(owd);         // set the directory back
```